# Как можно во время выделения моих чипсов, менять цвет их бекграунда или бордера?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть chips компонент. Не могу понять как мне реализовать функциональность выделения этих чипсов. Я хочу с зажатой ЛКМ выделять данные чипсы и что-бы у выделенных чипсов менялся бекграунд (например, на желтый) или бордер. Хочу что-бы по мере выделения чипсов (с зажатой ЛКМ) у них менялся background или border. Помогите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Вот мой codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glitter-dkh25?file=/src/App.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выделении чипсы должны выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.element::selection {
    background: yellow;
    /* Or smth else */
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я в курсе. Просто тут и сказать-то больше и нечего. Вообще странно, что человек идёт на Stackoverflow чтобы задать банальный вопрос, ответ на который гуглится за 5 секунд.

Comment: Object417 Спасибо конечно, но абсолютно не то, что мне нужно. Если бы данный псевдоэлемент подошел мне, я бы даже писать не стал.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Добавил то, как должны выглядеть чипсы после выделения